# .Net Core Application and FCN (File Change Notification)

Tags: .net, .net-5

Our .NET 5.0 application randomly restarts (Message in the log is "Application is shutting down.."). I suspect that one of the reasons is a shared folder that contains log files. Log files are "rolling" after certain size and the date changes.

I know that for .NET classic it was standard behavior: after application detects changes to files in the folder the AppPool was recycled. There is a special setting in httpRuntime called fcnMode that control that behavior.

My question is: does same apply to a .NET 5.0 application? I see no errors in Event Logs related to the application.

Comment: HttpRuntime is not available in .NET Core 1.0-3.1, and not available for .NET 5.0.

Comment: Thanks @Kit. Valid point. On the other hand, the fact that FCN mode parameter doesn't apply doesn't mean that shared folder is not a culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 99% of restarts are due to IIS App Pool "Idle Timeout" setting. Default is 20 minutes. For now I assume this is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Change the DWORD registry setting for

```
HKLMSOFTWAREWow6432NodeMicrosoftASP.NETFCNMode
```

to the value `1`, which will disable all file change notifications.